# My palindrome program written in pascal is giving me random answers.. Check my code

Tags: pascal, palindrome

```
program ideone;
var 
    s : string;
    t,len,i,j,count : integer;
begin
    readln(t);

    while t>0 do
    begin
        read(s);

        len := byte(s[0]);

        i :=0;
        j :=len-1;
        count :=0;

        while i<j do
        begin

            if s[i]<>s[j] then
            begin
                count :=count+1;
                    if count>1 then
                    begin
                        writeln('no');
                        break;
                    end;
            end;

            i :=i+1;
            j :=j-1;
        end;

        if count<2 then
            writeln('yes');

        t := t-1;
    end;

end.
```

I have to check whether changing only one character in the given string can make it a 'Palindrome'...

INPUT:
3
arora
abcd
mitin

OUTPUT:
yes
no
yes

Comment: As you clearly know, `s[0]` is the length byte. You can't also use it as the lower bound for access to chars (`s[i]` when `i  = 0`).

Comment: Thanx for that.... :) Btw I am learning pascal... Any book or site that you can suggest ? It will really help me..

Comment: And the highest char, by the same token, is `s[len]` where `len` is the length of the string. For beginners, there is a multitude of choices. Just Google "pascal tutorial" and dig in. But in the case of your code, it looks like you shifted from Pascal mode into C mode when you went from writing `len =  byte(s[0])` (better written, `len = length(s)`, and your loop counter settings, `i := 0; j := len-1;`.